# Статическая сборка QT 5.14.2+Msys2+Cmake+Gstreamer, как решить эти ошибки?

Tags: qt5, cmake, msys2, gstreamer

```
[1/5 5.7/sec] Automatic MOC and UIC for target vss-client
[2/4 9.0/sec] Automatic RCC for vss-client_en.qm.qrc
[3/4 10.3/sec] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/vss-client.dir/vss-client_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/qrc_vss-client_en.qm.cpp.obj
[4/4 3.4/sec] Linking CXX executable vss-client.exe
FAILED: vss-client.exe 
cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -std=c++11 -O3 -DNDEBUG  @CMakeFiles\vss-client.rsp -o vss-client.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libvss-client.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  && cd ."
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgstvideo-1.0: No such file or directory
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgstbase-1.0: No such file or directory
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgstreamer-1.0: No such file or directory
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
15:41:58: Процесс «C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\cmake.exe» завершился с кодом 1.
```

Ошибка при сборке/развёртывании проекта vss-client (комплект: mingw64.static).
Во время выполнения этапа «Сборка CMake».

Comment: английским по белому же написано "No such file or directory". линкуйте либы из места где их ld видит или указывайте полные путь с -L

Comment: В настройках проекта QT, указаны пути до папки с MSYS2, где находятся все либы, что еще нужно указать?